# How can I increase my samsung galaxy fit's battery life?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Fit(S5670) and running official 2.3.6 version. My battery's capacity is 1350mAh. Can I increase this capacity to 1500mAh or 2000mAh?

Comment: In my fridge is a bottle of beer, with a capacity of 0.33 litres. How can I increase its capacity to 0.5 or more litres? // I'm not making fun of you, just giving you a "picture" to grab the idea. You cannot increase the capacity of your battery, you only can replace your battery with one of higher capacity, as [Keshava writes](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/61371/16575).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I increase this capacity to `1500mAh` or `2000mAh`?

Did you mean increasing capacity from `1350mAh` to `1500mAh` on same battery??

It's **not** possible.

If your phone supports a battery with capacity `1500mAh` or `2000mAh`, you can buy a new battery with these increased capacity.

Check manufacturer's website for details of phone and batteries.

Comment: Ok, I will check on it.